# How can I delete a view from Couchbase using Python client?

Tags: couchbase

Is there a way to delete Couchbase client using the Python client?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way since it is not implemented in the SDK will be to call the REST API directly.

This API is documented here:
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-designdoc-api-deleting.html